# Is it possible to see if the value of a dictionary contains a X of a string?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary like so:

```
 dictionaryName = {'Key1':'Akins, Richard A. ', 'Key2':'Frederic, Matthew B. ', 'Key3':'Freeman, Gordon J. '}
```

Is it possible to write something that could take an input of say `Richard A.` or `Richard` and return `Key1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just use `in` if the text to search for is an exact substring of one of the values:

```
def search_dict(d, needle):
    return [k for k, v in d.items() if needle in v]

d = {'Key1':'Akins, Richard A. ', 'Key2':'Frederic, Matthew B. ', 'Key3':'Freeman, Gordon J. '}
print(search_dict(d, "Richard"))
```

If you only need to return the first key you can do:

```
def search_dict(d, needle):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if needle in v:
            return k
```

Comment: What if the text doesn't match exactly? Is it possible if they are looking for ```Key1``` and they enter in ``` 'Richard'``` is there a way to return ```Key1```

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify - this will work fine for any substring so "Richard" would match "Akins, Richard A.". If you need fuzzy matching that allows for different spelling etc. that would be harder.

Comment: Thank You!, I don't believe I need fuzzy matching, I was hoping to figure out if it is possible to give users the ability to still receive results even if they forget to include blank space or capitalization and it appears this does exactly that. I just couldn't wrap my head around if it was possible without a library.

Comment: If you want capitalization not to matter (case-insensitive match), use `needle.lower() in v.lower()`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use adict.items()

```
for k,v in adict.items():
    if "Richard A." in v:
        print(k)
# output: Key1
```

Answer (score 2):

You're basically looking for a fuzzy lookup but it seems your dict keys are supposed to be values and vice/versa. Also don't use `dict` as a variable name. Try something like this:

```
next(k for k, v in data.items() if 'Richard' in v)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example Python 3.6**

```
example_dict = {'Key1':'Akins, Richard A. ', 'Key2':'Frederic, Matthew B. ', 'Key3':'Freeman, Gordon J. '}

def get_key(d, value):
  for k,v in d.items():
    if value in v:
      print(f'Key: {k}')
      return v

get_key(example_dict, 'Richard A')
```